# react-navigate v5 and API. Couldn't find a 'component' or 'children' prop for the screen 'Home'

Tags: react-native

I took a simple example of NavigationContainer. I have a main Screen `<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />`
I created a new Component HomeScreen then connected with App.js
In my component HomeScreen I fetch data.
I does not work. My error:

> Couldn't find a 'component' or 'children' prop for the screen 'Home'. This can happen if you passed 'undefined'.

How could I do it? Thanks!

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { HomeScreen } from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import { SignInScreen } from './src/screens/SignInScreen';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SignInScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default HomeScreen = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.movies))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  });

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are exporting default `export default HomeScreen` but importing with destructing.

Change

`import { HomeScreen } from './src/screens/HomeScreen';`.

To

`import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';`

Comment: I am very dumb! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: this saved me a lot of time !!

Comment: Learning react-native now and I found I did same thing. Shows I have more to learn!